# If I turn error reporting off, do I not need to worry about anyone seeing my SQL tables?

Tags: php, sql, report, xss, code-injection

If I just disable error reporting across my website am I safe from anyone discovering the information in my SQL databases?

also, would this prevent XSS attacks completely?

Comment: These items are unrelated.  Though you can leak sensitve data via error reporting.  Turning it off doesn't protect you against SQL INjection, XSS, CSRF, etc.

Comment: I don't know (hence comment over answer), but I can almost guarantee that there is nothing you can do such that you never have to worry about security issues. They're always an issue. Also, turning off error reporting is a bad idea in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off error reporting is to preventing database injection/XSS attacks as closing your eyes is to preventing getting mugged. *Nothing* protects you from attacks like actually going through your code and covering up each individual security risk manually (whether that's blacklisting `exec()`-type commands, using prepared statements, timeouts, those too-many-failed-tries-counters, whatever it may be).

Answer (score 1):

It is never ever a good idea to disable error reporting. You should disable `display_errors()` and enable `log_errors()`.

Also this has nothing to do with [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). What helps against XSS is using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).